# Print lines after pattern in several files

Tags: bash, awk, scripting, grep

I have a file with the same pattern several times.
Something like:

```
   time
   12:00
   12:32
   23:22
   time
   10:32
   1:32
   15:45
```

I want to print the lines after the pattern, in the example `time`
in several files. The number of lines after the pattern is constant.
I found I can get the first part of my question with `awk '/time/ {x=NR+3;next}(NR<=x){print}' filename`
But I have no idea how to output each chunk into different files.

Comment: Crossposting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35667212/3776858

Answer (score 1):

Use line redirection in `awk`, e.g.

```
$ awk '{print "hello" >> "/tmp/hello"; print "world" >> "/tmp/world"}'
```

You might use an array for the files defined at the `BEGIN` then use it (in `awk`) like this:

```
BEGIN{files[1]="first-file";
      files[2]="second-file";
      line=0}
/time/{line=NR}
{print >> files[NR-line]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the contextual output options for `grep`.  If you want the three lines after each occurrence of `time` in (say) all files in a directory:

```
grep -A3 'time' /path/to/files/*
```

`grep` has three contextual options- `A` for lines After a match; `B` for lines Before a match, and `C` for full Context (lines both before and after a match).  If you want to further split the output of `grep` and you know that each match will give four lines of output, you can pipe the output to `split -l4`.

Answer (score 0):

With new GNU sed

```
nl -bptime filename | 
sed -n '/time/{N;N;N;s/\([0-9]\+\)[^\n]*\n/echo >\1.txt \"/;s/$/\"/e;}'
```

will print 3 lines after `time` each to file(s) *N.txt* where the `N` is correspond to `time` occurance in `filename`